# Spring MVC: Security configuration requireSecure() must redirect permanently 301

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redirect, spring-security

.and().requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()

I am forcing HTTPS with above configuration, the problem is its redirecting user temporarily (302). I want the http status code should be 301 (permanent redirect)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyAuthenticationProvider _auth;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(_auth);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.headers().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .someCodehere.
                .and().requiresChannel().antMatchers("/ping").requiresInsecure()
                .and().requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()
                .and().csrf().disable();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what works for me.

First defining our `RedirectStrategy` that uses status 301 and building `SecureChannelProcessor` around it.

```
final RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new RedirectStrategy() {
    @Override
    public void sendRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            String url) throws IOException {
        response.addHeader("Location", response.encodeRedirectURL(url));
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
};

final RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint entryPoint = new RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint();
entryPoint.setRedirectStrategy(redirectStrategy);

final SecureChannelProcessor secureChannelProcessor = new SecureChannelProcessor();
secureChannelProcessor.setEntryPoint(entryPoint);
```

Then configure with this `SecureChannelProcessor`:

```
http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure().channelProcessors(Arrays.asList(secureChannelProcessor)).and()
... other configuration
```

**How this works**

`.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()` adds `SecureChannelProcessor` instance which has `RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint`, which in turn has `RedirectStrategy`. So to change the redirection strategy, we have to build entry point and processor objects.

Please note that `response.flushBuffer()` is required when we make a redirect as Spring will continue processing the request unless the response is committed. `flushBuffer()` makes sure it is.

Please also note that `PortMapper` is used to change the port when redirecting. If you don't define it, the default one will be used which changes 80 to 443 and 8080 to 8443. If your ports are different, you may need to configure `PortMapper` as well and inject it into `RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint` instance.

For `InsecureChannelProcessor` everything is similar.

Comment: is there any maven dependency required for this?
` org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter@41921212': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL]`

Comment: Please add the full stack trace to the question

Comment: Don't you by chance add an `InsecureChannelProcessor` to `requiresSecure()`?

Comment: How about the full stack trace?

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thank you for sharing, shame it is so hard to get Spring to 301 instead of 302.